# How can I determine if a file is a zip file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I need to determine if a file in my app's documents directory is a zip file. The file name cannot be used in making this determination. So I will need to be able read the MIME type or find some other property that only applies to zips.

NOTE: A solution that requires putting the entire file into memory is not ideal as files could potentially be pretty large.

Comment: What network service you are using for downloading the file ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to http://www.pkware.com/documents/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT,
a ZIP file starts with the "local file header signature"

```
0x50, 0x4b, 0x03, 0x04
```

so it is sufficient to read the first 4 bytes to check if the file is possibly a ZIP file.
A definite decision can only be made if you actually try to extract the file.

There are *many* methods to read the first 4 bytes of a file. You can use NSFileHandle, 
NSInputStream, open/read/close, ... . So this should only be taken as one possible example:

```
NSFileHandle *fh = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:@"/path/to/file"];
NSData *data = [fh readDataOfLength:4];
if ([data length] == 4) {
    const char *bytes = [data bytes];
    if (bytes[0] == 'P' && bytes[1] == 'K' && bytes[2] == 3 && bytes[3] == 4) {
        // File starts with ZIP magic ...
    }
}
```

**Swift 4 version:**

```
if let fh = FileHandle(forReadingAtPath: "/path/to/file") {
    let data = fh.readData(ofLength: 4)
    if data.starts(with: [0x50, 0x4b, 0x03, 0x04]) {
        // File starts with ZIP magic ...
    }
    fh.closeFile()
}
```

Comment: How could I go about reading only the first 4 bytes, and checking it against that signature?

Comment: Interesting, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)) disagrees with that, saying only that this header is common.

Comment: @JWWalker: Yes, that is interesting. The ZIP format was introduced by PKWARE (as I understand it) so I have always used their document as the definite documentation. Up to now that always worked.

Comment: `List.exe` worked just fine for this - prefer using a small Windows utility to running a custom prog every time I want to see some binary data

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
NSWorkspace *ws = [NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace];
NSString *description = [ws localizedDescriptionForType:[ws typeOfFile:@"/full/path/to/file" error:nil]];
```

Or for mime this

```
+ (NSString*) mimeTypeForFileAtPath: (NSString *) path {
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path]) {
        return nil;
    }
    CFStringRef UTI = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, (CFStringRef)[path pathExtension], NULL);
    CFStringRef mimeType = UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass (UTI, kUTTagClassMIMEType);
    CFRelease(UTI);
    if (!mimeType) {
        return @"application/octet-stream";
    }
    return [NSMakeCollectable((NSString *)mimeType) autorelease];
}
```

Comment: I haven't tested your second example, but the first one definitely uses the file name. It will not recognize "file.abc" as ZIP file even if the contents is a valid ZIP archive.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just use **file**, then grep if it has the text "zip" or "Zip Archive" to be safe.

```
if file -q $FILENAME | grep "Zip archive"; then
  echo "zip";
else
  echo "not zip";
fi
```

Comment: a file name can always be spoofed

Comment: @NateH06 This isn't looking at the filename. It's running the file command. This will in fact detect a zip file, even if the extension of the file is wrong.