# Determine if a file is a zip file or an .xlsx file

Tags: excel, scala, zip, xlsx, unzip

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18194946/7082628) answer and another I can't find at the moment, I've built a function in Scala to determine if a given file path is a zip file or not. Apparently, the headers of zip files are signed with a specific set of magic numbers if they are an archive file.

My basic functionality for where I need this is: 1. take in a file 2. determine if a file is a zip file, 3a.If it is, unzip the file and move the resulting files. 3b. If it is not a zip file, just move the file. So first, the file is run through this function to determine if it is a zip file:

```
import java.io.{File, RandomAccessFile}

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils

def isZipFile(filePath: String): Boolean = {
      val file = new File(filePath)
      var fileSignature = 0
      if (file.exists()) {
        val raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r")
        try {
          fileSignature = raf.readInt()
        } catch {
          case e: Exception => println("Whoops")
        } finally {
          IOUtils.closeQuietly(raf)
        }
      }
      fileSignature == 0x504B0304 || fileSignature == 0x504B0506 || fileSignature == 0x504B0708
    }
```

However there's now a bit of a bug/edge case and the last line evaluating `fileSignature` is no longer always accurate. I sometimes have to pass .xlsx files through this (and also zip files full of .xlsx files). A .xlsx file IS a zip file, specifically, and in the above code, `fileSignature == 0x504B0304`, causes a flat .xslx file to evaluate to true.

(note: older/classic Excel files don't have this issue)

Is there any programmatic way to tell the difference between a .xlsx file and a zip file?

Comment: Do you have a problem with looking at the file suffix?

Comment: Yes, as sometimes the ".zip" or ".xlsx" is not reliably there. This can also be spoofed - I'm not worried about nefariously spoofed files, just the source of the incoming files may strip the suffix or accidentally add it on.

Comment: An Open XML file has a standard internal file structure. You can inspect the contents of a zipped file and if the file structure indicates it's an Open XML file, you go with that.

Comment: @Bob Sorry, I genuinely don't know - are Open XML's and .xlsx files related?

Comment: XLSX files use Open XML format: https://whatis.techtarget.com/fileformat/XLSX-Microsoft-Excel-Open-XML-Document

Comment: @BobDalgeish thanks! that's just what I'll have to do, it seems there's about 9-11 files that are always present. I'll just unzip it regardless and examine the contents, looking for a match based on the expected results.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I was looking for the same answer too. 
I got a lead. Look at https://gitlab.com/hrbrmstr/wand/blob/master/R/check-office.R

In R you can use this to determine differences between zip and xlsx (and docx etc)

This is the function you need `wand::get_content_type`

Few other leads

- [How to distinguish xlsx and docx files from zip archives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48188346/how-to-distinguish-xlsx-and-docx-files-from-zip-archives)
- https://github.com/minad/mimemagic#extra-magic-overlay

Answer (score 0):

Since both .zip and .xlsx having the same Magic number, I couldn't find the valid zip file.

So, I have used Apache Tika to find the exact document type.

Even if renamed the file as zip, it finds the exact file type.

Reference [Apache tika use cases](https://www.baeldung.com/apache-tika)

Answer (score -1):

A *.xlsx file is a *.zip file. Just try

"ren MyFile.xlsx MyFile.xlsx.zip"

and open it.

Seriously just give it a try i -:)

Comment: By doing that, you turn a zipfile into a zipped zipfile.

Comment: @Dominique no it just changes a zipped file with the extension '.xlsx' to a zipped file with the extension '.zip', `ren` is just renaming a file not zipping it. However either way the answer has no relevance, the OP knows that an '.xlsx' file is a zip file. The problem being that because it is a zip file the magic number for '.xlsx' is the same as for a zipped file and they want to know how to distinguish the two.